# UWP Mobile Run WACK test for mobile app

Tags: mobile, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, wack

I am new to Windows app development. I am building a C# app targeting UWP desktop & mobile platforms. I have read these links [MSDN-Link 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/windows-app-certification-kit) & [MSDN-Link 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/windows-app-certification-kit-tests)

Both these links doesnt seem to talk anything about running WACK tests for mobile. Any useful info will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am building a C# app targeting UWP desktop & mobile platforms.

WACK test is now enabled for the UWP workflows, there is no need to care the device platform, whether your app runs on desktop or mobile does not change UWP workflows, you can directly publish your app to store after WACK test for UWP app is finished.